# Javascript window.open(via extension) no access error

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-devtools

I have this function:

```
function openTab(url){
   var win = window.open(url, '_blank'); //same origin
   var interval = setInterval(function(win){
      if(win.closed()){
       console.log('closed');
       clearinterval(interval);
       }
    }, 500, win);
}
```

It works properly when I paste it in the browser(chrome) console.
But when I try to inject this code using chrome.tabs.executeScript in my chrome extension, the win.closed part returns:

> Uncaught TypeError: no access

I need to keep track of the newly open window on the opener one, but using chrome extension to do the injection, the win variable returns null.
I wonder how can I make this work the way it is, by injecting the code via extension in the opener window.

Comment: Use the native API: chrome.windows.create and chrome.windows.remove. Note, it's asynchronous.

Comment: but this way will I be able to track the opened window in the opener one or in the extension? If it is in the extension I'll have to reformulate a large bit of my code(which is not this one above but uses the same logic)

Comment: Your content script can use messaging to ask the background script to do things with that window like creating, closing, checking its existence. If you need more flexibility, you can inject another content script into that new window's tab, and also coordinate it via messaging.

Comment: @wOxxOm thank You! I'll have to change my approach to the code, it will cost me a few hours but I'll have to do it. Well, no pain no gain haha